# How to make zero a part of an int array in C?

Tags: c

This function works well aside from not accepting 0 because it considers it NULL

```
void addtolist(int list[], int item){
    for(int a=0;a<5;a++){
        if(list[a]==NULL){
            list[a]=item; 
            break; 
        }
     }
  }
```

Is there any way I can make the array accept zeroes? 
Additional info: -List- is a simple int array, accepting -item- inputs with scanf

Comment: `list[a]==NULL` is invalid, you should keep track of the current length used in your array.

Comment: This is the distinction between C strings (NUL-delimited, can't contain NULs) and Pascal strings (which have the length as a separate data item, and so *can* contain NULs). If you want to be able to contain `0`s in your contents, you need to store the length out-of-band.

Comment: If you must use an end-of-array marker, don't use NULL/0 - instead, pick some other value. Best of luck.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

No, there's no way to distinguish between `list[a] == NULL` and `list[a] == 0`. `list` is nothing more than a block of memory where every 4 bytes are considered be an integer.

The basic problem is you want to distinguish between elements which are empty and those which have a value. There's a few ways to handle this.

## Use a special integer.

You could define all negative numbers as "empty". Or, if you need negative values, perhaps just one value. `INT_MIN` is a good choice.

But special values lead to bugs, and there's no type checking to save you, and you need to specially initialize each list. There are better ways.

## Use integer pointers.

Instead of storing integers, store pointers to integers. Now `NULL` works.

```
int main() {
    int **list = calloc(10, sizeof(int*));
    int num = 42;
    list[5] = &num;

    for( size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
        int *entry = list[i];
        if( entry == NULL ) {
            continue;
        }
        printf("%d\n", *entry);
    }
}
```

The downside if you're storing pointers, so you have to remember to copy lest you alter the original memory. Also now `NULL` can't be used as a sentry to indicate the end of the array.

## Use a hash or tree

The real solution is to change your data structure to better match the job. An array is great if you have a complete, ordered list of things easily indexed with integers. If you have an incomplete list with gaps, a hash might be a better fit. Here's an example using [GLib's hash table](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Hash-Tables.html).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <glib.h>

// A little convenience function for inserting integers into a hash
// that normally wants pointers.
gboolean hash_table_insert_int(
    GHashTable *table, int key, int value
) {
    return g_hash_table_insert( table, GINT_TO_POINTER(key), GINT_TO_POINTER(value) );
}

int main() {    
    GHashTable *numbers = g_hash_table_new(g_direct_hash, g_direct_equal);

    // Add 5 -> 42 and 9 -> 23
    hash_table_insert_int( numbers, 5, 42 );
    hash_table_insert_int( numbers, 9, 23 );

    // Iterate through the entries in the table.
    GHashTableIter iter;
    gpointer key, value;
    g_hash_table_iter_init(&iter, numbers);
    while( g_hash_table_iter_next(&iter, &key, &value) ) {
        printf("%d -> %d\n", (int)key, (int)value);
    }
}
```

GLib's data structures take some getting used to because it's designed to be type generic, but it's worth it for the robust flexibility they bring. Now you have a data structure which you can explicitly insert and delete entries without messing with special values, it knows its memory boundaries, and is memory and performance efficient.